# Failing to understand set-theoretic issue in Borceux

Tags: logic, category-theory, set-theory, foundations

The following is an excerpt of "Handbook of Categorical Algebra 2" by Borceaux, chapter 8 on fibered categories.

> Working with set-indexed families as in the previous example very often leads to constructions or arguments which look innocent... but are formally incorrect! For example given an $I$-indexed family of morphisms $(f_i : C_i \to D_i)_{i \in I}$ in $\mathsf{Set}(\mathscr{C})$, few people really worry about considering the "set"
>
> $$I_0 = \{ i \in I \mid f_i \text{ is a monomorphism} \}.$$
>
> But the sentence "$f_i$ is a monomorphism" means
>
> $$ \forall C \in \mathscr{C} \ \forall u,v \in \mathscr{C}(C, C_i) \quad f_i \circ u = f_i \circ v \implies u = v$$
>
> ... and no axiom of set theory will ever imply that $I_0$ is a set, since the formula contains a quantifier acting on a variable $C$ which runs through something (namely, $\mathscr{C}$) which is not a set!

I am terrible at foundations, and I absolutely do not understand the arguement he is making here.
So, the $C_i, D_i$ are objects in $\mathcal{C}$, and $I$ is a set (that's by definition).
In particular, $I_0$ as defined there is a "subclass" of $I$, and hence a set, no?
Or is this some sort of decidability-issue? That is, membership in $I_0$ is not decidable in our (smallish) universe, and therefore we cannot properly build $I_0$?

I'd also be happy to get pointers at some resources where such issues are properly discussed, and not only marginally :(

Comment: I've edited your question to use mathjax (which is searchable) rather than an image (which isn't) so that other users have an easier time finding this question. In the future you should do the same ^_^

Answer (score 4):

I think Borceux's argument is wrong. Recall Comprehension scheme 1.1.8 from Volume I:
"If $\phi(x_1,...,x_n)$ is a formula where quantification just occurs on set variables, there exists a class $A$ such that $(x_1,\dots,x_n)\in A$ if and only if $\phi(x_1,\dots,x_n)$." Quantification over sets in the context of Bernays-Godel set theory means bounded quantification, e.g. having "$\forall x\in C$" instead of "$\forall x$" (this is because $x\in C$ implies $x$ is a set). Borceux seems to erroneosuly think that $C$ itself in "$\forall x\in C$" should be a set instead of a class for the comprehension scheme to apply.

The confusiong perhaps stems from not formulating the more general comprehension scheme with parameters: given $\phi(x_1,\dots,x_n,Y_1,\dots,Y_m)$ with bounded quantifiers, then $\forall Y_1,\dots,Y_m\exists A((x_1,\dots,x_n)\in A\iff\phi(x_1,\dots,x_n,Y_1,\dots,Y_m)$. Here $x_1,\dots,x_n$ should be set-variables, i.e. we are assuming $\phi(x_1,\dots,x_n,Y_1,\dots,Y_m\implies\exists Z_i(x_i\in Z_i)$.

Now, clearly the sentence that "$f_i$ is a monomorphism", i.e. "$\forall C \in \mathscr{C} \ \forall u,v \in \mathscr{C}(C, C_i) \quad f_i \circ u = f_i \circ v \implies u = v$", involves only bounded quantification. So by 1.1.8 there is a class of monomorphisms in any category. Presuming that $Set(\mathscr C)$ is a category (which it is because set-indexed families of elements of a class form a class), $I_0=\{i\in I:f_i$ is a monomorphism$\}$ is then a subclass of $I$ (since "$f_i$ is a monomorphism" is a class) and is therefore a set.